# Convert integer value in minutes & seconds using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a web application where a person want to book a table. Before payment, the table is reserved for that person for 30 minutes. If he doesn't make any payment his reservation is deleted.

I want to display a count down timer of Minutes and seconds to that person so that he may know how much time left in reservation before payment.

I know how to use timer but how should I use it in my case?

The reservation time is saved in database. I want the timer to start like 30:00 and start decreasing the time. Should I initial value from database ? or just set its value to something like 30:00 ? I don't know what to do. please help

```
 Protected Sub UpdateTimer()
    Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    UpdateTimer()
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are asking for a UI feature with is done in the client browser, this mean you should be using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Help ..

```
Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)

Protected Sub UpdateTimer()
    ts = ts.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    Label1.Text = ts.Minutes & ":" & ts.Seconds
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ts.Minutes <= 0 And ts.Seconds <= 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        '<!-- DO SOMETHING HERE -->
    Else
        UpdateTimer()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

I'd never used asp but i think they're just the same

Comment: Thanks @kiLLua . will check

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim timercount As Integer = 30 //Value For 3 Minutes

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lblTimer.Text = timercount.ToString() + " Second."
    If timercount = 0 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("Your booking has been cancelled", "My Application", _
      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    Else
        timercount -= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How could i display both minutes and seconds ?

Comment: @Panky26 based on his tags, it's a web app, not a windows form.

Comment: @the_lotus we can use it in both, where i think right ?